# get value of default_statistics_target on postrgesql

Tags: postgresql, performance

I want to see the value of `default_statistics_target` on `postgresql` before running

```
SET default_statistics_target=1000
```

Its most likely the default (100) but would like to see it.

Where it can  be found ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are two questions:

- Where default(100) value is declared?
- How can I see `Stats target` value before applying `SET default_statistics_target=1000`

### Where default(100) value is declared?

You can see it in the [source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/misc/guc.c#L2092)

> ```
> {
>       {"default_statistics_target", PGC_USERSET, QUERY_TUNING_OTHER,
>           gettext_noop("Sets the default statistics target."),
>           gettext_noop("This applies to table columns that have not had a "
>                        "column-specific target set via ALTER TABLE SET STATISTICS.")
>       },
>       &default_statistics_target,
>       100, 1, 10000,
>       NULL, NULL, NULL
>   },
> ```

### How can I see `Stats target` value before applying `SET default_statistics_target=1000` ?

Let's suppose that column `bar` of table `foo` has  `attstattarget=500`:

```
alter table foo alter column bar set statistics 500;
```

So, there are two ways to show `attstattarget`

- SQL_query:

```
SELECT attrelid::regclass, attname, attstattarget FROM pg_attribute WHERE attstattarget > 0 order by attstattarget desc;

 attrelid | attname | attstattarget
----------+---------+---------------
 foo      | bar     |           500
```

- `\d+` command:

```
\d+ foo

                                                            Table "public.foo"
          Column           |            Type             |                  Modifiers                   | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 bar                       | varchar                     | not null                                     | plain    | 500          |
```

** Note**: `Postgres` doesn't show `stats target` until it distinct from default value.

### `300` - yet another magic number

Thx to [this comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/200136/postgresql-what-the-default-statistics-target-value-really-means#comment450743_200177), you can read a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.1734&rep=rep1&type=pdf) about another magic number and check it in the [source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/commands/analyze.c#L1832):

> ```
> /*
>    * Determine which standard statistics algorithm to use
>    */
>   if (OidIsValid(eqopr) && OidIsValid(ltopr))
>   {
>       /* Seems to be a scalar datatype */
>       stats->compute_stats = compute_scalar_stats;
>       /*--------------------
>        * The following choice of minrows is based on the paper
>        * "Random sampling for histogram construction: how much is enough?"
>        * by Surajit Chaudhuri, Rajeev Motwani and Vivek Narasayya, in
>        * Proceedings of ACM SIGMOD International Conference on Management
>        * of Data, 1998, Pages 436-447.  Their Corollary 1 to Theorem 5
>        * says that for table size n, histogram size k, maximum relative
>        * error in bin size f, and error probability gamma, the minimum
>        * random sample size is
>        *      r = 4 * k * ln(2*n/gamma) / f^2
>        * Taking f = 0.5, gamma = 0.01, n = 10^6 rows, we obtain
>        *      r = 305.82 * k
>        * Note that because of the log function, the dependence on n is
>        * quite weak; even at n = 10^12, a 300*k sample gives <= 0.66
>        * bin size error with probability 0.99.  So there's no real need to
>        * scale for n, which is a good thing because we don't necessarily
>        * know it at this point.
>        *--------------------
>        */
>       stats->minrows = 300 * attr->attstattarget;
>   }
>   else if (OidIsValid(eqopr))
>   {
>       /* We can still recognize distinct values */
>       stats->compute_stats = compute_distinct_stats;
>       /* Might as well use the same minrows as above */
>       stats->minrows = 300 * attr->attstattarget;
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       /* Can't do much but the trivial stuff */
>       stats->compute_stats = compute_trivial_stats;
>       /* Might as well use the same minrows as above */
>       stats->minrows = 300 * attr->attstattarget;
>   }
> ```